# How to use more than one index in for each loop and Insert data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am trying to fetch the data from API and inserting it in MySQL table.
In the process, I am using a for-each loop to get an array of data. How can I avoid using loop many times and just use indexes in one loop itself?

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testing');
$url = 'MYAPI';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err)
{
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else
{
    $source = json_decode($response);
    if (is_array($source) || is_object($source))
    {
        foreach( $source->DATA as &$data )
        {
            $data = array_combine( $source->COLUMNS, $data );
        }

        $CLIENTCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'CLIENTCODE') );
        $BRANCHCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'BRANCHCODE') );
        $FAMILYCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'FAMILYCODE') );
        $CLIENTNAME = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'CLIENTNAME') );
        $BRANCHNAME = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'BRANCHNAME') );

        foreach ($CLIENTCODE as $cc)
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO holding (CLIENTCODE) VALUES('$cc')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
        }

        foreach ($BRANCHCODE as $bc)
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO holding (BRANCHCODE) VALUES('$bc')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can add multiple value in single mysql query, put all data as values shown below then execute DB insert query once**

***Query syntex***

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

**Example**

```
<?php 

$vals = ""; // empty var for store values 
$array = ["John", "Ram", "Mohan"]; // sample array 

foreach($array as $val) {
    $vals .= "('".$val."'),"; 
}

$vals = rtrim($vals,',');
$query = "INSET INTO tbl(name) VALUES $vals";

// Now Execute query to insert 
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, and I would add the suggestion that the OP could buffer data as it comes in, and then execute inserts with multiple records.

Comment: okay I got it,, only one question :Below are my columns which are arrays itself how to convert them like you said : $array = ["John", "Ram", "Mohan"]; ::::::

 $CLIENTCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'CLIENTCODE') );
    $BRANCHCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'BRANCHCODE') );
    $FAMILYCODE = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'FAMILYCODE') );
    $CLIENTNAME = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'CLIENTNAME') );
    $BRANCHNAME = ( array_column( $source->DATA, 'BRANCHNAME') );

Comment: @Amrinderkumar 
  array_column already returns the values from a single column in the input array. like  ["John", "Ram", "Mohan"];

  try print_r($CLIENTCODE)

Comment: The o/p for print_r($CLIENTCODE) is:  Array ( [0] => DEL0102 [1] => DEL0102 [2] => DEL0102 [3] => DEL0102 [4] => DEL0102 [5] => DEL0102 [6] => DEL0102 [7] => DEL0102 [8] => DEL0102 [9] => DEL0102 [10] => DEL0102 [11] => DEL0102 [12] => DEL0102 )

So I have to do like this :
$array = ["$CLIENTCODE", "$BRANCHCODE", "$FAMILYCODE"];  ??

Comment: @Amrinderkumar Just replace $array with $CLIENTCODE and modify query a/c your need ..